# .setBounds not working for JLabel and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, layout-manager

I am trying to change the positioning of a JLabel and a JButton on my GUI. Even though I try to use .setBounds to change their locations; they both just appear in the top centre of the screen.

```
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class yo implements MouseListener {

Image image;
JButton button = new JButton("Wassup");
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel heloo = new JLabel("yo");
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("hi.jpg");
        image = i.getImage();
        g.drawImage(image,150,150,null);
        g.drawString("Hello",100,100);
        g.drawString("Hi",50,50);
    }
};


public yo()
{
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setTitle("Hello");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel.add(heloo);
    panel.add(button);
    button.setBounds(200,100,200,100);
    heloo.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    button.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
{
    heloo.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
}
public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent Event){}
public void mouseExited (MouseEvent Event){}
public void mousePressed (MouseEvent Event){}
public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent Event){}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new yo();
}
}
```

I apologise about all of the imports, I don't really know which ones I need and which ones are just pointless.

Basically I would like some help on how to change the positioning of my components.

Comment: That's one thing I like about Eclipse; it will figure out what imports you need and add them for you.

Comment: Don't use setBounds() to set the size and location of a component. Let the layout manager do its job. That is if fact what is happening. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout, so the components are being positioned based on the rules of the FlowLayout.

Comment: 1) In general, avoid importing whole packages (`import awt.*`) as it is bad practice, 2) if they are from the Java API, you can leave them out of the question as most people will already know the classes.

Comment: I like the imports included with a SSCCE because I don't use an IDE and I don't like typing them in myself.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use setBounds() to set the size and location of a component.

Let the layout manager do its job. That is if fact what is happening. A JPanel uses a `FlowLayout`, so the components are being positioned based on the rules of the FlowLayout. You can change the FlowLayout to align components to the left if you want. Or you can use a different layout manager.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to find other layout managers you can use.

Comment: I did it, using .setLayout(null);

I know it's 'bad practice blahedeblah', but I want to create a custom GUI.

Comment: @JamesLoughlin, That is NOT how you create a custom GUI!! There is absolutely no reason to do this. There are many different layout managers you can use to position two components on a panel. Spend time learning good programming practices not bad programming practices.

Comment: @Cornelius, of course the layout managers work. And of course you need a better requirement than  - `I would like some help on how to change the positioning of my components.` - before we can give a better answer on which layout manger (or combination of layout managers) to use. Each requirement is different.

Comment: No, really, I've tried every Swing manager, and couple of third party ones,  I can say they are pure crap. Give me a layout manager that can do [this](https://hulk.raywenderlich.com/original/3X/8/8/88e76f445e67c387e3671eab0e3728dd2d9f7fac.jpg)  or [this](http://agames.cc/wp-content/thumbs/mochi/L/lateral-the-word-association-game_img2.jpg) in a less than 100 lines of code and I'll admit that they really manage something.

Comment: @Cornelius, Why would you make such a ridiculous comment? Given the context of this question  - which is to position a label and button you would absolutely use a layout manager. If you can't figure out a layout manager to position these two components then you obviously don't understand layout managers. If you have some other weird requirement, then ask a proper question stating the actual requirements. The answer to the question in this posting is to use a layout manager.

Comment: As coming from web design world, which has a problematic layout managers, I was horrified to see that much worse situation is in the programming world of Java. It simply is the truth, that Swing has no decent Layout manager. They are on 1992. level.  If you're lost in a desert the obvious answer will be to drink urine, but that doesn't make it a decent drink. People are wasting enormous amount of time getting components where they want. Pure number of questions like these, where people can't set 2 components out, is the pointer on where Java is with layouts.

Comment: @Cornelius - `where people can't set 2 components out` - layout managers are a new concept for people who are used to other languages that don't support them. So yes, there is a learning curve the same way there is a learning curve for any new concept. The OP here was not even trying to use a layout manager, which is why a link to the tutorial was given.

Comment: `Swing has no decent Layout manager.` - completely wrong. There are layout managers that are easy to use and solve a high percentage of "common" layout problems. Of course there is no single layout manager to solve all problems. The same way there is no program to solve all business problems. That is why we write code, to handle new and changing requirements. Layout managers are a good approach to minimize the amount of code needed for different requirements.

Comment: `Give me a layout manager that can do this or this...` - there is never a single tool that does everything. That is why we have hammers and screw drivers. You pick the appropriate tool for the job. Just because a tool you know about doesn't do a specific job for you doesn't mean the concept of the tool is wrong. I'm sure virtually every person owns a hammer and screw driver because they are such handy tools. Same with layout managers. They make a large percentage of layouts easier.

Comment: Never have I said that I have something against a layout manager, but I absolutely disagree with you that Swing has a decent set of Layout Managers. First,  managerS must have not be in plural, but all possible layouts must have been realized by just ONE layout manager that then would call for different layouts. And what's most important, those different layouts had to be implemented in the same way, and not in syntax chaos like this. It could have had more flexibility and be more simple.

Comment: Swing is just hell to work with. It's obvious that no plan was made while designing the layouts. It's like they made up 2 layouts, and then months later when some other guys encountered  the problem with their components they added their own layout to achieve desired look, and then later some people added their own. It's like different people with different approach piled up on each other, without regards to anything but resolving their current problem in the least amount of time. That GridBay is literally insane. I'd like to meet a person who made that up to hear what was the idea behind it.

Comment: @Cornelius,  `I absolutely disagree with you that Swing has a decent set of Layout Managers` - well your opinion is irrelevant in the context of this question. The simple answer to the question is to use one of the provided layout managers. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. If you don't like it them don't use them. If you have a better solution then post it.

Comment: I'd have a lot more to say, but SO is noticing that this is starting to be a conversation, so we better stop.

Answer (score 4):

```
public yo() {
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setTitle("Hello");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(heloo);
    panel.add(button);
    button.setBounds(200,100,200,100);
    heloo.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    button.addMouseListener(this);
}
```

By setting the layout of the JPanel to null, it will be in the "Absolute Layout", and then you'll be able to set the position of the JLabel and JButton with setBounds().

Comment: -1 while technically correct, it propagates worst practice in gui development

Comment: That's what he wanted to know. He should use his time learning the best programming practices, but he must know the worst practices as well. By doing in a poorly-written way, he'll assimilate someday why it was written in a poorly-written way, and then he'll understand the necessity of avoiding this particular bad practice.

Comment: this helped to solved my prob! altho yes it is bad practice. appreciate the contributor who answered directly to the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
    JLabel jlabel=new JLabel();
    jlabel.setText(" operation calculator");
    jlabel.setBounds(3,40,450,40);
    
    jlabel.setForeground(Color.green);
    
    jlabel.setBackground(Color.blue);`enter code here`
    jlabel.setOpaque(true);
    jframe.add(jlabel);
```