# Objects get handled wrong when read from text file, why?

Tags: java

I read objects (strings really but I convert them to the objects) from a text file that are stored on seperate lines.

EDIT: My problem is that the objects get drawn out on top of eachother when they get added to the panel. The objects have their own seperate X and Y coordinates which they're supposed to be drawn in.

Like so (this is the saved text file that I read from):

```
Described,Bus,182,73,PlaceWithDesc,random desc
Named,Bus,53,31,Place1
Named,train,84,100,Place2
```

tokens[0] is just a hard coded string

[1] is a category of transport (it is an object that gives the place the color of its triangle when it gets drawn out on the picture panel)

[2] is the x coordinate of the object Position and [3] is the Y coordinate.

[4] is the name of the Place when the object got constructed.

If [0] is equal to Described then the Place also gets created with a description.

```
            FileReader inFile = new FileReader("place.reg");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inFile);

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");  
                Category category = null;
                String categoryName = tokens[1];

                if (categoryName.equals("Bus")) {
                    category = transportCategory[0];
                } else if (categoryName.equals("Underground")) {
                    category = transportCategory[1];
                } else if (categoryName.equals("Train")) {
                    category = transportCategory[2];
                } else if (categoryName.equals("None")) {
                    category = transportCategory[3];
                }

                String placeName = tokens[0];
                int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
                Position pos = new Position(x, y);
                String name = tokens[4];

                if (placeName.equals("Named")) {
                    NamedPlace nPlace = new NamedPlace(pos, category, name);

                    add(nPlace);
                    picturePanel.add(nPlace);
                    nPlace.addMouseListener(placeMouseLis);

                    System.out.println("named place added: " + 
nPlace.position().getX() + " , " + pos.getX());
                } else if (placeName.equals("Described")) {
                    String description = tokens[5];
                    DescribedPlace dPlace = new DescribedPlace(pos, 
category, name, description);

                    add(dPlace);
                    picturePanel.add(dPlace);

                    System.out.println("desc place was added");
                }
            }
                 //  Iterator<Map.Entry<Position, Place>> iterator = 
                 //  allPlaces.entrySet().iterator();
                 //  while(iterator.hasNext()){
                 //  Place place = iterator.next().getValue();
                 //  picturePanel.add(place);
                }
                inFile.close();
                in.close();
```

Now my problem is that when I add the Place objects the get drawn out on top of eachother. Note that NamedPlace and DescribedPlace are subclasses to a superclass Place.

EDIT: I solved it by doing picturePanel.repaint(); and picturePanel.validate();

Comment: Maybe its something about the Layout overriding the "Bounds" value that you set. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264761/setbounds-not-working-for-jlabel-and-jbutton

Answer (score 0):

I'm the biggest idiot.. I forgot to do repaint(); and validate(); on my picturePanel once all the objects were read in.