# Rows are not visibal in table

Tags: java, database, swing, applet, awt

[image: Output image]

I want to create table which displays the detail of patient from its patient ID but my data is not displaying in the table i am new to java can anyone help me to solve this problem pleas give me solution to this problem there is no error or warning showing while compiling and running the program  `String tbcol[]` is to come first and then below that Data from database should be displayed here is my program also is there any mistake in my `SELECT Query`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel; 
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Adi extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
            ImageIcon icon; 
            ImageIcon img4;
            Dimension dimension;
            JLabel imglab4,symp,diag,med,wr,twr;
            JTable tab1;
            JTextField pidtxt,tsymp,tdiag,tmed;
            JCheckBox cwr;
            JComboBox<String> ctwr;
            Connection conn1;
            Statement st;
            DefaultTableModel model;
     Adi(){    
                dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
                int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - 700)/2);
                int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - 500)/2);
                setLocation(x, y);
                setSize(700,500);
                setLayout(null);
                setUndecorated(true);
                icon = new ImageIcon("image/microscope.png");
                setIconImage(icon.getImage());
                setResizable(false);
                JLabel plable = new JLabel("Patient ID");
                plable.setBounds(225,50,80,30);
                add(plable);
                pidtxt = new JTextField();
                pidtxt.setBounds(290,50,100,30);
                add(pidtxt);
                JButton btnshr=new JButton("Search");
                btnshr.setBounds(400,50,80,30);
                add(btnshr);
                String tbcol[]={"Patient ID","Patient Name","Contact Number","Age","Gender","Blood Group","Address","Any Major Disease"};
                model=new DefaultTableModel();
                tab1= new JTable(2,8);
           /*     model.addRow("Patient ID"); //Didn't worked
                model.addRow("Patient Name");
                model.addRow("Contact Number");
                model.addRow("Age");
                model.addRow("Gender");
                model.addRow("Blood Group");
                model.addRow("Address");
                model.addRow("Any Major Disease");*/
                model.addRow(tbcol);
                tab1.setBounds(100,125,500,30);
                add(tab1);
                symp = new JLabel("Symptom's");
                symp.setBounds(100,225,80,30);
                diag = new JLabel("Diagnosis");
                diag.setBounds(100,275,80,30);
                med = new JLabel("Medicines");
                med.setBounds(100,325,80,30);
                add(symp);
                add(diag);
                add(med);
                tsymp = new JTextField();
                tsymp.setBounds(170,225,180,30);
                tdiag = new JTextField();
                tdiag.setBounds(170,275,180,30);
                tmed = new JTextField();
                tmed.setBounds(170,325,180,30);
                add(tsymp);
                add(tdiag);
                add(tmed);
                wr = new JLabel("Ward Required");
                wr.setBounds(425,225,100,30);
                add(wr);
                cwr = new JCheckBox("Yes");
                cwr.setBounds(550,225,80,30);
                add(cwr);
                twr = new JLabel("Type of Ward");
                twr.setBounds(425,275,100,30);
                ctwr = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"General","Single","Duo"});
                ctwr.setBounds(550,280,100,20);
                add(twr);
                add(ctwr);
                JButton btnsaadi=new JButton("Save");
                JButton btncoadi=new JButton("Close");
                btnsaadi.setBounds(200,400,80,30);
                btncoadi.setBounds(425,400,80,30);
                add(btnsaadi);
                add(btncoadi);
             //   Background image 
                img4 = new ImageIcon("image/m_back.jpg");
                imglab4 = new JLabel(img4);
                imglab4.setSize(600,600);
                add(imglab4);
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ael){
                  String adistr =ael.getActionCommand();  
                   if(adistr.equals("Search")){
                      try {
                        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                        conn1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://Hospital.accdb");
                        st = conn1.createStatement();
                        String sql="select * from Patient where PatientID='"+pidtxt.getText()+"'";
                        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                              
                                while(rs.next()){
                                    String patientID =rs.getString("PatientID");
                                    String pname =rs.getString("Pname");
                                    String contactNumber =rs.getString("ContactNumber");
                                    String ages=rs.getString("ages");
                                    String gender=rs.getString("gender");
                                    String bloodGroup=rs.getString("bloodGroup");
                                    String address=rs.getString("address");
                                    String anyMajorDisease=rs.getString("anyMajorDisease");
                                    String tbdata[]={patientID,pname,contactNumber,ages,gender,bloodGroup,address,anyMajorDisease};
                                    model.addRow(tbdata);
                                }
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                                 ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                   }
                }
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Adi adi=new Adi();
         adi.setVisible(true); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);` don't do this or `suchAndSuch.setBounds(...)`. Learn and use the layout managers for best visualization of your GUI on all platforms.

Comment: Also, first put the JTable into the viewport of a JScrollPane and then add the scroll pane to the GUI.

Comment: The main issue here is, that you have a `DefaultTableModel` and a `JTable` which you never actually use in conjunction. Therefore, you can add all rows you want to your `model`, but the `tab1` will never actually display anything. Either get the model of the table via `tab1.getModel()` or set the model you created to your table like `new JTable(model)` / `tab1.setModel(model)`.

Comment: So what can I use for setting location of jtable setLocation

Comment: Ok so how do I fix it

Comment: But please, before you continue, check out the tutorials for [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html), specifically [How to use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Laying out Components within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264761/setbounds-not-working-for-jlabel-and-jbutton. While it is true that one should NOT use a null layout and setBounds(...) to set the location of components, the core issue of this question is the JTable, The code using the table is completely wrong and if the layout issue is fixed, the table will still not display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String tbcol[]={"Patient ID","Patient Name","Contact Number","Age","Gender","Blood Group","Address","Any Major Disease"};
model=new DefaultTableModel();
tab1= new JTable(2,8);
/*model.addRow("Patient ID"); //Didn't worked
tab1.setBounds(100,125,500,30);
add(tab1);
```

The above code is fundamentally wrong for the following reasons:

1. You need to define columns in the `TableModel`. If there are no columns, there will be nothing to display
2. You need to add rows of data to the `TableModel`. If there are no rows, there will be nothing to display
3. The `TableModel` needs to be added to the `JTable`. If the `JTable` has no `TableModel` there will be nothing to display
4. Your logic to use setBounds is creating a height of 30. Each row in a JTable is 16 pixels, so you would only ever see two rows of data. This is one reason why you should never use setBounds(). You should use a `layout manager` which allows the component to dynamically resize as the data in the table changes. Also, the component should be allowed to resize as the frame size changes.
5. The `JTable` needs to be added to the viewport of a `JScrollPane`. This will allow you to scroll the data in the table when you have more that two rows.
6. The `JScrollPane` needs to be added to the frame. If you add the `JTable` to the frame,  only the rows of data will display. By adding the `JTable` to the viewport of the scroll pane you will see the columns names as a header the the rows of data in the table.

So the basic structure of the above code should be:

```
String tbcol[]={"Patient ID","Patient Name","Contact Number","Age","Gender","Blood Group","Address","Any Major Disease"};
model=new DefaultTableModel(tbcol, 0);
tab1= new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( tab1 );
scrollPane.setBounds(100,125,500,30);
add(scrollPane);
```

The above code will create a `JTable` with just the column headers and no data. Your logic to read data from the ResultSet will then use the `addRow(...)` method to add rows of data to the model.

As mentioned by other you should NOT be using a null layout and setBounds(). Read the tutorial links provided for examples of properly using a JTable, with a JScrollPane and using Layout Managers.

Comment: Thanks that really helped