# the last label is not setting according to the given setbound()

Tags: java

eveybody I was creating a login page where i am face a issue the last label is not setting according to the given setbound so i created a label named fake and gave it a null value and put it at the last so the my design does not get effect but i need a solution for this why is it happening.i have inserted a image as a logo at the starting

```
 package com.MyBank;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
class LoginDesign  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f;
    JButton b1,b2,b3;
    JPasswordField pass;
    JTextField tx1;
    JLabel l1,l2,l3,img,fake;
    Font f1;



    public LoginDesign()
    {

        f1=new Font(Font.MONOSPACED,Font.BOLD,23);
        f=new JFrame("Automatic Teller Machine");
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //label for Image
        img=new JLabel("");
        img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\vineet mendon\\Desktop\\bot\\bankLogo.png"));
        img.setBounds(135,10,270,70);
        f.add(img);

        //label for welcome to atm
        l1=new JLabel("⚜️ WELCOME TO ATM ⚜️");
        l1.setBounds(135,100,300,30);
        l1.setFont(f1);
        f.add(l1);
         //label for card no
        l2=new JLabel("Card No:");
        l2.setBounds(80,170,150,30);
        l2.setFont(f1);
        f.add(l2);
        //textfield for card no
        tx1=new JTextField(16);
        tx1.setBounds(210,170,200,30);
        tx1.setFont(f1);
        f.add(tx1);
        //create   pin no
        l3=new JLabel("Pin No :");
        l3.setBounds(80,230,150,30);
        l3.setFont(f1);
        f.add(l3);
        //creating password field
        pass =new JPasswordField(4);
        pass.setBounds(210,230,200,30);
        pass.setFont(f1);
        f.add(pass);
        //creating  for sign -in
        b1=new JButton("Sign In");
        b1.setBounds(80,290,160,30);
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b1.setFont(f1);
        f.add(b1);

        //creating button for clear
        b2=new JButton("Clear");
        b2.setBounds(250,290,160,30);
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b2.setFont(f1);
        f.add(b2);

        //creating button for sign-up
        b3=new JButton("Sign-Up");
        b3.setBounds(80,350,330,30);
        b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b3.setFont(f1);
        f.add(b3);

        //fake label i used==>this is problematic code
        fake=new JLabel("hiii");
        fake.setBounds(200,150,200,20);
        f.add(fake);

        //seting the frame size
        f.setSize(550,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setLocation(400,70);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }

}
public class Login  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginDesign();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please, indicate where you have problems in your code.

Comment: problematic is label named fake it is not taking the custom given set bound by me and set the label in the middel and this happing only to the last label like if i delete the fake label then the label present the last will be button b3 it will set into a random location

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264761/setbounds-not-working-for-jlabel-and-jbutton

Comment: i used jpanel but has now messed up every things flow layout is not working for me

Comment: explain me why is it happening

Comment: **Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds()**. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Use one or more panel with appropriate layout managers to achieve your desired layout. We have no idea what you want your form to look like so we can't suggest the solution.

Comment: ok thank sir I got it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.